# TestNG report with customized error in place of stack trace, when my script fails

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using Testng and selenium, if my script is fail then it shows the total stack trace in report but i need only custom message to know the error.

Error is comming like this:

```
 FAILED: abc
java.lang.AssertionError: url:http//:abc.com
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at com.ebates.qa.dotcom.test.MerchantImages.storeSmallIconImageVerification(MerchantImages.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

but actually i don't want to this stacktrace
i need a custom message in place of stacktrace..

Comment: It's an exception, so yes, you would see the stack trace.

Comment: in testNG report i want to display  custom error message, not the stacktrace..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the protected method ReduceStackTrace() from the SkipException class.

Create a new class and extend it with SkipException and add this.reduceStackTrace() in the constructor.

Now while throwing the exception - throw with the newly created class. it will print only 2 lines in console instead of lot of lines as previous.

```
public class MyException extends SkipExecution
{
// auto generated constructer
public MyException(String skipMessage)
    {
    super(skipMessage);
    this.reduceStackTrace(); // this should be added.
    }
```

}

Now use this class to throw ur skipException.

```
throw new MyException("Hi dude");
```

Comment: Makes you wonder why they added that method, but didn't make it public or include the child class that called it.

Answer (score 2):

You could add custom `TestListener` to your code like:

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        Throwable th = tr.getThrowable();
        if (th != null) {
            System.out.println(th.getMessage());
            tr.setThrowable(null);
        }
    }
}
```

and add listener to test case class:

```
@Listeners({TestListener.class})
public class myTest() {
    . . . // tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make a custom reporter (which is, extend the one currently in use and override the method that prints the trace out) and use your reporter in your configuration.

Source code is available at https://github.com/cbeust/testng/tree/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters.

Main documentation for reporters customization is available at http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging.