# Selenium Webdriver Testng : How to fail a test in assertion and send meaningful message in a report instead of "Nosuchelementexception" trace

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Their are numerous resources on internet but I couldn't find a simple answer to my problem.

I want my test case to fail and report a one liner meaningful message instead of full stack trace.

I tried using try, catch, if, else but I want my test to fail not to pass and throw message.

Scenario - Load url, if url doesn't load throw error and abort test and move to next iteration of loading next url

Any solution ?

Comment: Have you got solution for same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try... `try catch`

```
try {
    doStuff();//this code is failing
}
catch (YourExpectedException e){ //catch the correct exception here
    //this passes your custom message AND the caught exception
    //should also stop the test
    throw new AssertionError("This is my custom message", e); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the "Nosuchelementexception" trace is still displayed in the report. How to get rid of that and print only the custom message ?

Comment: I don't know if possible and it shouldn't be possible just by specifying some flag or property. You want the stacktrace. Look here for custom TestListener that can exclude your exception. You can just check if it's your type of exception by adding another line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141369/testng-report-with-customized-error-in-place-of-stack-trace-when-my-script-fail

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how to do it. I would like to suggest you the most simple and beautiful ways.

1) Checking exception and if exception on of you specify you will execute some code or do something. Here is the example:

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    Throwable exception = result.getThrowable();
    if (exception instanceof org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException
            ||
            exception instanceof org.openqa.selenium. NoSuchElementException) {
        Assert.fail("Some message or code");
    }
}
```

2) 
You can implement **WebDriverEventListener** in your project.

What it means?

It means that WebDriver allow to execute some logic before and after some events. You can add try-catch in the implementation of methods.

Example:

```
    @Override
    public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
      // your code
}

    @Override
    public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
      // your code
}

    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
      // your code
}

    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
      // your code
}
```

Here is more detail example: [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/)

Comment: Thanks, but for a beginner like me, it might take some time to understand this concept, I went through the full tutorial but still couldn't figure out the way, I'll try to read again.

Comment: For the start you can try just add logging using this approach. Create a class which will implement WebDriverEventListener, override all needed methods and add logging.

Example:

https://github.com/LearnByBhanuPratap/PageObjectWithPageFactoryFramework/blob/master/src/main/java/com/test/automation/uiAutomation/customListner/WebEventListener.java

Comment: I am already using reporter.log in my framework, its just that it doesn't fail the status but does log the status as per the code (element enabled/present or not on webpage), I wanted to have something where assert fail doesn't throw stacktrace but custom message.

Comment: Hello, I added new approach. I suppose this way will be the best. You can check an exception and do some logic or do Assert.fail();  Please check.